# Huffman compression: binary code turns into decimal

Tags: c++

Here is the code for converting text into binary code and write it into other file.

```
void encodedhuff(unordered_map<char,int>& encoding_scheme, string& filename ){
    ifstream file(filename); 
    ofstream outfile;

    outfile.open("pride.huff", std::ios_base::app);
    if (!file.is_open()){ 
        std::cout << "unable to open the file.\n"; 
        exit(1); 
    }

    char ch; 
    while(file.get(ch)){ 
        std::unordered_map<char,int>::const_iterator got = encoding_scheme.find (ch);
        if (got!=encoding_scheme.end())
            outfile<<got->second<<" "; 
    }
    file.close();
    outfile.close();
}


int main(){ 
    unorderd_map<string,int>codes={{'a',0010},{'b',0111},{'c',1101}};
    

    std::string filename = "abc.txt";

    auto charFreq = fileReading(filename);


    //NodePtr tree=nullptr; 
   // buildHuffmanTree(charFreq, tree);

    
    printCodes(tree, "");
    encodedhuff(code,filename);
}
```

content of text file is abc . the compressed file should have 001001111101 but it is outputing 8731101

Comment: `unorderd_map<string,int>codes={{'a',0010},{'b',0111},{'c',1101}};` is your problem. `0010` is an octal literal and will be a number in base 8. It will not look like `0010` when printed. You may want `unorderd_map<char,std::string>codes={{'a',"0010"},{'b',"0111"},{'c',"1101"}};` but you don't really get compression if all Huffman codes are the same length.

Comment: LIterals starting with `0` are octal; `0010` is eight (not two), `0111` is seventy-three (not seven) , and `1101` is written in decimal and is one thousand, one hundred and one (not thirteen). (Writing a number using just zeros and ones does not make it a binary number.)